# Trying to load 2d texture with glTexImage2D, but just getting blank

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to create a 2d texture to display on my Qt/OpenGL application.  I then created a Quad that fills up screen to place it, but I all I ever get is a white screen without any errors.  Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

```c++
#include "AppGLWidget.h"

#include <iostream>

AppGLWidget::AppGLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent),
  mnRange(100),
  mcDisplayedImage(512,512,QImage::Format_ARGB32)
{
  mcDisplayedImage.fill(qRgb(100,0,0));

  mcDisplayedImage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(mcDisplayedImage);

  int value;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &value);
}

AppGLWidget::~AppGLWidget(void)
{
}

void AppGLWidget::initializeGL() {
  glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
  glPushMatrix();
  glOrtho(0, size().width(), size().height(), 0, -1, 1);
  glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)size().width(), (GLint)size().height());
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(1,&mcTextureObj);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,mcTextureObj);    
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);       
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mcDisplayedImage.width(), mcDisplayedImage.height(), 0, 
      GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  // check OpenGL error
  GLenum err;
  while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << std::endl;
  }
}

void AppGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
  glPopMatrix();
  glPushMatrix();
  glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void AppGLWidget::paintGL() {

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mcTextureObj);   

  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, mcDisplayedImage.width(), mcDisplayedImage.height(),  
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mcDisplayedImage.bits());

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex2i(0,lnHeight);  
  glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex2i(0,0);
  glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex2i(lnWidth,0);
  glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex2i(lnWidth,lnHeight);

  glEnd();

  // check OpenGL error
  GLenum err;
  while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_TEXTURE_2D` needs to be `glEnable()`'d for rendering.

Right now you're `glDisable()`ing it in `initializeGL()` and leaving it that way.